# JavaScript - Converting JSON object to String

Tags: javascript

I have a JSON object in following format which I need to convert to pure String...as 0000-0000-0000-0000-000 so I was wondering how I can do this in Javascript?

```
{ KEY: "0000-0000-0000-0000-000" }
```

Comment: That is not even close to being valid JSON.

Comment: Unfortunately this is the return of a REST API call, which return content type json

Comment: well, whatever, but it is absolutely not parseable as JSON.

Comment: Apologies my mistake, it get returned as Key: then the key itself

Comment: OK, well unless `KEY` is in double-quotes ( `"KEY"` ), it's *still* not valid JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this (where data is the data returned from the API call)

```
var tokenString = data.KEY;
alert(tokenString);
```

Answer (score 0):

try 
console.log(obj)
to view it in the browser debugger console

or
JSON.stringify(obj);

Comment: JSON.stringify won't return it as string but will convert it for sure as json obj

Comment: You can not use JSON since this is not a valid json.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using

```
JSON.stringify()
```

Extra info on this method can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Answer (score 0):

Your object is not JSON when it's in JavaScript, it's JavaScript code. The string version you're asking for is JSON (JavaScript Object Notation). This is why you can do things in JavaScript that you cannot do in JSON, like representing functions and binary data.

The function you're looking for to turn your JavaScript object into JSON is `JSON.stringify()` which you would use like this:

```
var obj = { }; //put your object here
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj)); //output the JSON version of your object
```

Also, the object in your question is not valid JSON or JS. In either scenario you'd need to put quotes around the `0000-0000-0000-0000-0000` and give it a value. The following is valid JSON:

```
{ "0000-0000-0000-0000-0000": null }
```

Answer (score 0):

Store your response in one variable and then do

```
response.KEY
```